# BJTs - Large DC Signal Analysis - Negative Voltages

Tags: voltage, bjt

[image]

So there's this circuit here. I'm a bit confused with the negative voltage in order to find out the base current.

I sort of did a hack-ish guess and did a KCL at the node at the left of the base. I assumed the current was going into the node from both +15 and -15 V sources which added up to get i_b going into the base.

I ended up with the right answer but I still don't feel like I fully grasp the concept of a negative voltage. Could someone explain this to me better?

Answer (score 2):

There is really only one trick here- to find out whether the BE junction is forward biased or not. Just like you'd do with a diode, imagine the base connection open and what voltage would appear there- is it more than 0.7V? Since it is (it looks like it would be about +5V) we can assume the junction is conducting, and thus the base voltage is fixed at 0.7V.

Now it's straightforward to calculate the base current as (15-0.7)/470K + (-15-0.7)/1M.

If you swapped the two base resistors, you'd have the opposite situation and could simply ignore the base and calculate the base voltage as if it was a simple voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

What you see usually in schematics like these are *node voltages*, i.e. voltages which implicitly are referenced to ground.

Keep in mind that any voltage is *always defined between two points* and with a reference polarity. The point and the polarity are usually drawn on a schematic using an arrow (or plus "+" and minus "-" signs) between those points:

[image]

This is often cumbersome for complex schematics, so we choose a common reference node, which we call (circuit) ground and write only the value of the voltages near the nodes. Those voltages are referenced to ground implicitly, as I already said, and this means that a positive/negative voltage is positive/negative with respect to the ground node.
The trick is that the voltage between any other two nodes can be obtained as a difference between two node voltages, as illustrated by this picture (take node C as ground):

[image]

\[
v_{AB} = v_{AC} - v_{BC}
\]

This latter is a direct consequence of KVL.

In your case the base terminal is at +0.6V (relative to ground) and the lower leg of the 1M resistor is at -15V (relative to ground), hence across that resistor you have a voltage of:

\[
0.6V - (-15V) = 15.6V
\]

(positive side on the base of the BJT). I assumed the BE junction has ~0.6V across it because I assumed you want to bias your BJT in the active region, as it is needed for it to work as an amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is Ohms law.
Write down Ohms law for 470k and for the 1Meg resistor using a good estimate for the B-E voltage (VE=0, thus VBE=VB). That is all you can do because the exact value for VB depends strongly on the particular BJT unit (tolerances,...).
Don`t forget that the current through 470k resistor is (I1+IB) and the current through the lower resistor is I1 only. 
Thus, you have two equations for the two unknown values IB and I1.